# When the login is executed twice with Laravel Sanctum an exception is thrown

Tags: laravel, laravel-sanctum

I´m using **Laravel 10 with Sanctum** (and Fortify) for authentication. CSRF & Login works fine but when I call the **route /login** for an **already logged in user** again (so "logging an an already logged in user"), the following exception is thrown:

```
The attribute [login] either does not exist or was not retrieved for model [App\Models\User].
```

I would expect that the session is simply regenerated in this case and I can´t explain why that happens.